# How to reinitialize/retrigger animations made with Animations system?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-animations

i'm new to `@angular/animations` and now i came across something. I have a simple list that when you select an item it shows a sublist, both lists have the same animation, but if a select a different item on the first list the second list doesn't animates again. I've tried assigning the second list to `null` and then giving the new values, thought this would be enough to make the animation trigger again.

A workaround i'm using is a `setTimeout` that waits for 100ms before assigning the new values, it works fine, but the screen blinks, here's my code:

MY COMPONENT.HTML:

```html
<ion-list>
    <!-- FIRST LIST -->
    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">By Animal</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item [@listAnimation]="services.length" class="scrollable-x">
        <ion-avatar *ngFor="let serv of services" item-start (tap)="setSelectedType(serv)">
          <img src="/path/to/image.png">
          <p>{{serv.type}}</p>
        </ion-avatar>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>

    <!-- SECOND LIST: DYNAMIC LIST -->
    <ion-item-group *ngIf="selectedType">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">Services: {{selectedType}}</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item [@listAnimation]="selectedTypeServices.length" class="scrollable-x">
        <ion-avatar *ngFor="let serv of selectedTypeServices" item-start>
          <img src="/path/to/image.png">
          <p>{{serv.name}}</p>
        </ion-avatar>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </ion-list>
```

MY COMPONENT.TS:

```js
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
import { trigger, style, transition, animate, keyframes, query, stagger } from "@angular/animations";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-agendar",
  templateUrl: "agendar.html",
  animations: [
    trigger("listAnimation", [
      transition("* => *", [
        query(":enter", style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),

        query(
          ":enter",
          stagger("300ms", [
            animate(
              ".7s ease-in",
              keyframes([
                style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-75%)", offset: 0 }),
                style({
                  opacity: 0.5,
                  transform: "translateX(25px)",
                  offset: 0.3
                }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0)", offset: 1.0 })
              ])
            )
          ]),
          { optional: true }
        )
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AgendarPage {
  public services: Array<{ type: string; services: Array<{ name: string }>}> = [];

  public selectedType: string;
  public selectedTypeServices: any[];

  constructor(){}

  setSelectedType = service => {
    this.selectedType = null;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedTypeServices = service.services;
      this.selectedType = service.type;
    }, 100);
  };
}
```

So is there a way of reinitialize or retrigger the animation? Maybe some option i'm missing, a different function other than `trigger()` or anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the main reason your animation isn't "retriggering" per say is due to your state configuration of angular animations.  There are two ways of handling animations in angular:

1.) **State Method**

```
trigger('cube', [
  state('front', style({
    transform: 'rotateX(0deg)',
  })))
```

2.) **Transition Method**

```
trigger(
  'myAnimation',
  [
    transition(
    ':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', opacity: 0}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(0)', 'opacity': 1}))
    ]
  ))
```

You seem to be mixing the two and that's where your problem is stemming from I believe.

If you're using the **State Method** for your html you say something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div [@cube]="state">
```

**Typescript**

```
trigger('cube', [
  // States that can occur from viewing the front panel
  state('front', style({
    transform: 'rotateX(0deg)',
  })),
  state('bottom', style({
    transform: 'rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50vh) translateZ(50vh)',
  }))
  // Front animations when landing on page
  transition('front => bottom', animate('1500ms ease-in-out')),
  transition('bottom => front', animate('1500ms ease-in-out'))
])
```

You would initialize the state on ngOnInit() to be bottom or front for example and then switch on a click or something like that.  Note that the animations take place because the element is changing "states" and that variable is dictating the change.

If you choose the **Transition method**, you would have something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="hasUpload=='yes'" [@myAnimation]>
```

**Typescript**

```
trigger(
  'myAnimation',
  [
    transition(
    ':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', opacity: 0}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(0)', 'opacity': 1}))
    ]
  ),
  transition(
    ':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(0)', 'opacity': 1}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', 'opacity': 0})),
    ]
  )]
)
```

Note the difference here is that the animation is taking place based on whether or not the element is shown.  So the variable within the ngIf statement is dictating whether or not the animation will occur.

When you use `[@listAnimation]="services.length"` the services.length is useless as far as I can tell because you are using the transition method instead of states.  I believe that what you want to do can be accomplished by using the state method and change the state based on what service on your list is clicked. Then toggle the state and the animation should occur.  You're basically doing that already with the timeout, that's why it's working to some degree.  So instead of using your timeout, flop the states with a ternary operation and you should be good to go.  Hope that clears up some ambiguity!  Best of luck! :D

Comment: Your explanation solved my problem, using `services.length` was not animating again because my arrays'll in most of the cases have the same size, changed from `[@listAnimation]="services.length"` to `selectedType` and solved for me. I'll try some different code to understand better what you've explained, but anyways thanks a lot